# What is the proper way to respond to DynamoDB table change?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I came across this question from online during AWS study and wonder if anyone can shed me with more light:

> A company has setup an application in AWS that interacts with
>   DynamoDB. It is required that when an item is modified in a DynamoDB
>   table, an immediate entry is made to the associating application. How
>   can this be accomplished? Choose 2 answers from the choices below.

```
A.  Setup CloudWatch to monitor the DynamoDB table for changes. Then trigger a Lambda function to send the changes to the application.

B.  Setup CloudWatch logs to monitor the DynamoDB table for changes. Then trigger AWS SQS to send the changes to the application.

C.  Use DynamoDB streams to monitor the changes to the DynamoDB table.

D.  Use an AWS Lambda function on a scheduled basis to monitor the changes to the DynamoDB table
```

Answer (score 1):

I think C and D are good to go.

1. DynamoDB streams to monitor the changes
2. Lambda is good for near-realtime
3. CloudWatch is not fast enough
4. AWS SQS is Queue. Application need pull message => not fast

Comment: CloudWatch has been designed to monitor to maintain the reliability, availability, and performance of DynamoDB, not for tracking change task.

Comment: @hoangdv: You are right, I mean both CW and CW logs does not fit case

Comment: D isn't correct.  A lambda function on a schedule does not fit the criterion of "immediate."